# HTTP | language-tags vs. language-ranges

Tags: http

Reading through the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.4) I came across the terms “language-tag” and “language-range”. The standard defines the difference between these two entities as the following:

> A language-range matches a language-tag if it exactly equals the tag, or if it exactly equals a prefix of the tag such that the first tag character following the prefix is "-".

However, the document doesn't augment this statment by any of examples. So, how does the language-range differ from the language-tag in the following HTTP header field:

```
Accept-Language: en, en-gb, en-us
```

And if they don't differ here, could you give any examples where they do.

**Updated**

---

I'd rephrase the aforementioned citation in the following manner:

> A language is considered acceptable if its tag or the tag's prefix exactly equals a language range which was specified in the Accept-Language field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC does provide an example. If you look at the specification of the Accept-Language request header:

> The Accept-Language request-header field is similar to Accept, but
> restricts the set of natural languages that are preferred as a
> response to the request. Language tags are defined in [section 3.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.10).

> ```
>   Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":"
> ```

```
                     1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )
```

> ```
>   language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
> ```

> [...]

> ```
>   Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
> ```

> [...] "I prefer Danish, but will accept British English and
> other types of English."

Section 3.10 mentions:

> The name space of language tags is administered by the IANA.

So all **language tags** are registered [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry). Enter RFC 2616:

> A **language-range** (*as used in an Accept-Language header*) matches a **language-tag** if
> it exactly equals the tag, or if it exactly equals a prefix of the
> tag such that the first tag character following the prefix is "-".

So, `en` in `Accept-Language: en` matches `en-gb` and `en-US`. If the client expects multiple matches for a single range, it should specify the subtags and assign a quality value (`;q=`) per subtag for best results.

If it doesn't, the server gets to decide which available representation it will return.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in my question's example `language-range` is the set `en`, `en-gb` and `en-us`, but `language-tag` is any element of the set, and thus we have three tags and only one range. If this is true, why is the BNF not `language-range := 1#(language-tag)` or `language-range := 1#(1*8ALPHA ["-" 1*8ALPHA])`?

Comment: @Shamaoke _"3.10 Language Tags - A language tag identifies a natural language [...] a language tag is composed of 1 or more parts: A primary language tag and a possibly empty series of subtags"_. Tags are registered. If you use a complete language-tag or its prefix in an Accept-Language header, it is referred to as a language-range. The asterisk is to match any subtag. A language-range of `en-*` equals `en`, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 4):

A language tag is an identifier for a specific language. A webpage written in a specific language might be tagged with that language's tag, e.g. `en-US` for US English (as opposed to other English dialects, like UK English or Australian English). `en` is also a valid language tag for the English language in general.

A language *range* is what your browser says it prefers to receive from the webserver. It is a range, because it might not match exactly the language of the resource: if your browser says it likes the language range `en`, this means that `en`, `en-US`, `en-UK` are *all* acceptable — the range `en` matches the exact tag `en`, as well as all tags starting with `en-`.

As you can see, `en` is both a language tag *and* a language range. The difference between the two is in their usage: tags identify the specific language of content and are sent from the webserver to the client, while ranges identify language preferences and are sent from the client to the webserver.

*All* values in the `Accept-Language` request header are language ranges. Language tags are used in the `Content-Language` *response* header.

Answer (score 3):

`en` is a range and it matches the tag `en-gb` because it exactly equals a prefix of `en-gb` (that prefix being `en`) and the first character following the prefix (`en`) is `-`.